# tf.keras.Sequential binary classification model predicting [0.5, 0.5] or close to

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, tf.keras

I am currently trying to build a model to classify whether or not the outcome of a given football match will be above or below 2.5 goals, based on the Home team, Away team & game league, using a `tf.keras.Sequential` model in TensorFlow 2.0RC.

The problem I am encountering is that my softmax results converge on `[0.5,0.5]` when using the `model.predict` method. What makes this odd is that my validation & test accuracy and losses are about 0.94 & 0.12 respectively after 1000 epochs of training, otherwise I would have put this down to an overfitting problem. I am aware that 1000 epochs is extremely likely to overfit, however, I want to understand why my accuracy increases until about 800 epochs in. My loss flattens at about 300 epochs.

I have tried to alter the number of layers, number of units in each layer, the activation functions, optimizers and loss functions, number of epochs and learning rates, but can only seem to increase the losses.

The results still seem to converge toward `[0.5,0.5]` regardless.

The full code can be viewed at https://github.com/AhmUgEk/tensorflow_football_predictions, but below is an extract showing model composition.

```
# Create Keras Sequential model:
model = keras.Sequential()

model.add(feature_layer)  # Input processing layer.

model.add(Dense(units=32, activation='relu'))  # Hidden Layer 1.
model.add(Dropout(rate=0.4))
model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(Dense(units=32, activation='relu'))  # Hidden Layer 2.
model.add(Dropout(rate=0.4))
model.add(BatchNormalization())

model.add(Dense(units=2, activation='softmax'))  # Output layer.

# Compile the model:
model.compile(
    optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0001),
    loss=keras.losses.MeanSquaredLogarithmicError(),
    metrics=['accuracy']
)

# Compile the model:
model.compile(
    optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0001),
    loss=keras.losses.MeanSquaredLogarithmicError(),
    metrics=['accuracy']
)

# Fit the model to the training dataset and validate against the 
validation dataset between epochs:
model.fit(
    train_dataset,
    validation_data=val_dataset,
    epochs=1000,
    callbacks=[tensorboard_callback]
)
```

I would expect to receive a result of `[0.282, 0.718]` for example for an input of:

```
model.predict_classes([np.array(['E0'], dtype='object'),
    np.array(['Liverpool'], dtype='object'),
    np.array(['Newcastle'], dtype='object')])[0]
```

but as per the above, receive a result of say `[0.5, 0.5]`.

Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: It may happen that your model is not able to learn the distinct features between your 2 classes and thus it's confidence score is same for both. You can tweak your Network to see if there is any change in result. If you still cannot figure out the problem, you can share your model code and sample data and I will try to give you more inputs on that.

Comment: Hi Rishab. Thanks for the comments. As above, I have been tweaking the network, however, I still cannot get to grips with how the the `model.evaluate` method is claiming such good accuracy and loss stats when the results are effectively inconclusive. Also, as per my query, my full code is available via [link](https://github.com/AhmUgEk/tensorflow_football_predictions).

Comment: I was going through your code, as I can see that the training loss of the model has stopped decreasing after a few epochs. I am still trying to debug the problem, will share something once I am done.

Comment: Thanks Rishab, any advice would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: Why are you using the MeanSquaredLogarithmicError as loss?

Comment: After re-reviewing (and realising that the MSLE loss is suited to regression problems off the back of your advice), I have changed to `tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy()`  but still have the same issue, with a higher loss value - circa 0.68.

Answer (score 0):

I had made some minor changes in the model. Now, I am not getting exactly [0.5, 0.5].

**Result:**

```
[[0.61482537 0.3851746 ]
 [0.5121426  0.48785746]
 [0.48058605 0.51941395]
 [0.48913187 0.51086813]
 [0.45480043 0.5451996 ]
 [0.48933673 0.5106633 ]
 [0.43431875 0.5656812 ]
 [0.55314165 0.4468583 ]
 [0.5365097  0.4634903 ]
 [0.54371756 0.45628244]]
```

**Implementation:**

```
import datetime
import os
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf

from gpu_limiter import limit_gpu
from pipe_functions import csv_to_df, dataframe_to_dataset
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.layers import BatchNormalization, Dense, DenseFeatures, Dropout, Input
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import TensorBoard, ModelCheckpoint
import tensorflow.keras.backend as K
from tensorflow.data import Dataset


# Test GPU availability and instantiate memory growth limitation if True:
if tf.test.is_gpu_available():
    print('GPU Available\n')
    limit_gpu()
else:
    print('Running on CPU')

df = csv_to_df("./csv_files")

# Format & organise imported data, making the "Date" column the new index:
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df = df[['Date', 'Div', 'HomeTeam', 'AwayTeam', 'FTHG', 'FTAG']].dropna().set_index('Date').sort_index()
df['Over_2.5'] = (df['FTHG'] + df['FTAG'] > 2.5).astype(int)
df = df.drop(['FTHG', 'FTAG'], axis=1)


# Split data into training, validation and testing data:
# Note: random_state variable set to ensure reproducibility.
train, test = train_test_split(df, test_size=0.05, random_state=42)
train, val = train_test_split(train, test_size=0.05, random_state=42)

# print(df['Over_2.5'].value_counts())  # Check that data is balanced.


# Create datasets from train, val & test dataframes:
target_col = 'Over_2.5'
batch_size = 32

def df_to_dataset(features: np.ndarray, labels: np.ndarray, shuffle=True, batch_size=8) -> Dataset:
    ds = Dataset.from_tensor_slices(({"feature": features}, {"target": labels}))
    if shuffle:
        ds = ds.shuffle(buffer_size=len(features))
    ds = ds.batch(batch_size)
    return ds

def get_feature_transform() -> DenseFeatures:
    # Format features into feature columns to ensure data is in the correct format for feeding into the model:
    feature_cols = []
    for column in filter(lambda x: x != target_col, df.columns):
        feature_cols.append(tf.feature_column.embedding_column(tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list(
            key=column, vocabulary_list=df[column].unique()), dimension=5))
    return DenseFeatures(feature_cols)

# Transforms all features into dense tensors.
feature_transform = get_feature_transform()
train_features = feature_transform(dict(train)).numpy()
val_features = feature_transform(dict(val)).numpy()
test_features = feature_transform(dict(test)).numpy()

train_dataset = df_to_dataset(train_features, train[target_col].values, shuffle=True, batch_size=batch_size)
val_dataset = df_to_dataset(val_features, val[target_col].values, shuffle=True, batch_size=batch_size)  # Shuffle not required to validation data.
test_dataset = df_to_dataset(test_features, test[target_col].values, shuffle=True, batch_size=batch_size)  # Shuffle not required to test data.

# Create Keras Functional API:
# Create a feature layer from the feature columns, to be placed at the input layer of the model:

def build_model(input_shape: tuple) -> keras.Model:

    input_layer = keras.Input(shape=input_shape, name='feature')

    model = Dense(units=1028, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='normal', name='dense0')(input_layer)  # Hidden Layer 1.
    model = BatchNormalization(name='bc0')(model)

    model = Dense(units=1028, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='normal', name='dense1')(model)  # Hidden Layer 2.
    model = Dropout(rate=0.1)(model)
    model = BatchNormalization(name='bc1')(model)

    model = Dense(units=100, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='normal', name='dense2')(model)  # Hidden Layer 3.
    model = Dropout(rate=0.25)(model)
    model = BatchNormalization(name='bc2')(model)

    model = Dense(units=50, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='normal', name='dense3')(model)  # Hidden Layer 4.
    model = Dropout(rate=0.4)(model)
    model = BatchNormalization(name='bc3')(model)

    output_layer = Dense(units=2, activation='softmax', kernel_initializer='normal', name='target')(model)  # Output layer.

    model = keras.Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=output_layer, name='better-than-chance')

    # Compile the model:
    model.compile(
        optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001),
        loss='mse',
        metrics=['accuracy']
    )
    return model

# # Create a TensorBoard log file (time appended) directory for every run of the model:
# directory = ".\\logs\\" + str(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S"))
# os.mkdir(directory)

# # Create a TensorBoard callback to log a record of model performance for every 1 epoch:
# tensorboard_callback = TensorBoard(log_dir=directory, histogram_freq=1, write_graph=True, write_images=True)

# Run "tensorboard --logdir .\logs" in anaconda prompt to review & compare logged results.
# Note: Make sure that the correct environment is activated before running.

model = build_model((train_features.shape[1],))
model.summary()

# checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint('model-{epoch:03d}.h5', verbose=1, monitor='val_loss',save_best_only=True, mode='auto')  

# Fit the model to the training dataset and validate against the validation dataset between epochs:
model.fit(
    train_dataset,
    validation_data=val_dataset,
    epochs=10)
    # callbacks=[checkpoint]

# Saves and reloads model.
# model.save("./model.h5")
# model_from_saved = keras.models.load_model("./model.h5")

# Evaluate model accuracy against test dataset:
# scores, accuracy = model.evaluate(train_dataset)
# print('Accuracy:', accuracy)

##############
## OPTIONAL ##
##############

# DUBUGGING
# inp = model.input                                           # input placeholder
# outputs = [layer.output for layer in model.layers]          # all layer outputs
# functors = [K.function([inp], [out]) for out in outputs]    # evaluation functions

# # Testing
# layer_outs = [func([test_features]) for func in functors]
# print(layer_outs)


# # # Form a prediction based on inputs:
prediction = model.predict({"feature": test_features[:10]})
print(prediction)
```

1. One thing you can do is to try some ensemble Learning methods like
   [RandomForest](https://towardsdatascience.com/random-forest-in-python-24d0893d51c0)
   and
   [XGBoost](https://machinelearningmastery.com/gentle-introduction-xgboost-applied-machine-learning/)
   and compare the results.
2. You should try is to add other Key Performance Indicators(KPI)s in
   your data and then try to fit the model.

Comment: Thank you for your efforts in exploring the model with me. A couple of questions. Firstly, I note that you have made the model-construct a function. Is it so that later the model can be disabled and predictions made against the saved version? (I was planning to implement a save / load function in the next iteration, but wanted the model to be up and running first). I also note that you have kept 'MSE' as the loss function, though as mentioned above this is orientated more toward regression problems? finally, does 1028 tensors not seem high for a model with 3 features? Thank you for your effort

Comment: MSE is generally used for regression problems, the problem with MSE is that over time the gradients gets smaller which is generally not in case of cross entropy loss. And you don't need 1024 neurons in the Dense layers. I was just playing around with the model. Also implementation of the model is based on Keras Functional API rather than a Sequential one.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have had a chance to review your version of the model, however, I am still converging towards `[0.5, 0.5]` after 20 epochs, regardless of whether I use the functional API or sequential, with my loss getting stuck at about 0.7 for `CategoricalCrossentropy` and about 0.25 for `MSE`. Do you have any other ideas as to what might be causing the loss to stop improving after the first few epochs? I will be exploring whether or not adding features assists in reducing the loss as I believe it may be a limitation of the data. Thank you again for all of your assistance.

Comment: At the end of my answer, I told you to work on your data. Do some Feature Engineer and try to do some Exploratory Data Analysis. You can use **Pandas Profiling** to have a quick overview. The model learns from data, so if you don't feed in good data, no matter how good regularization and optimization tricks you apply, you will not get the desired performance.